# How can I change the size of selection in input type time in html?

Tags: html, datetime, input, time, font-size

hello i want to change the font size of this can you help with this?

```html
<input type="time" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="DO" name="do" id="inputy_d" required autocomplete="off">

<style>
#inputy_d{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: no size of input but size of selection (list with hours and minutes)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

use Below CSS:

```
font-size: 50px;
```

Comment: thank you but i dont want this size i want to change size of list, when you on clock the list of hours and minutes is showed and i want to change font size of this list

Comment: *click on clock